# Does a US citizen need a visa to go to Australia to put on a conference and go on vacation?

Tags: visas, australia, us-citizens

I'm going to Australia for both business and pleasure for two weeks. Do I need a special visa for this?

Answer (score 8):

The relevant visa for this case seems to be [ETA (Business Entrant - Short Validity) subclass 977](http://www.immi.gov.au/skilled/business/956-977/). Since you mentioned you're going for a conference, a longer validity business visa should not be required. It can be applied for online.

Visitor/tourist visas will probably not fit as only '[limited volunteer work](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/976/obligations.htm)' is allowed under them.

Comment: I don't get what you mean about the longer validity for the conference? The whole trip should be two weeks.

Comment: @Michael: Oops, typo. I missed out a 'not' after 'should'.

Comment: Yes the visa Ankur mentions is the visa you require. It gives you permission to stay in Australia for 3 months in one visit, but you can also make as many visits you like over the course of a year.